# Utility that counts the number of files in a directory (recursively)?

Tags: windows

Is there any small Windows utility that counts the number of files in a directory recursively (including subdirectories) ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The folder's properties will do it for you:

[image]

You can also use dir along with find from the command line:

```
dir /a-d /s /b folder_name | find /c ":"
```